# Table Font Size is not Changing After Applying Font Tag

Tags: html, font-size

i am new to HTML i am creating a table and i want table font size same as whole web page's font size so i added a font tag with size attribute.
this tag changed font size of ravery text on web page but table font is not affected

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>use of table</title>
</head>
<body>
 <center> 
 <font size="80" style="red"><p>Hello World this is a font check</p></font>

 <table border="3">
  <tr><td>Roll No</td> <td>195612</td> </tr>
   <tr><td>Name</td> <td>Rajesh</td></tr>
   <tr><td>Age</td> <td>23 (Twenty Three )</td> </tr>
   <tr><td>Father's Name</td> <td> Nayar</td> </tr>
   <tr><td>City</td> <td>Siwas Pali</td> </tr>
   </table>
</center>
</body>


</html>
```

Comment: Short non-answer: `<font>` was superseded by CSS in 1996 (and `80` was never a valid value for `size` anyway). Stop using `<font>`. Learn CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it that way. `font-size` is a CSS property.

To change the `font-size` of html elements you need to use some CSS like this:

```
<style>
    p, table{
        font-size: 20px;
        color: red;
    }
</style>
```

You can either add this to your code and remove the `<font>` tag or you can create a separate file and use it adding this inside your `<head></head>` tags:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="..url.." />
```

Here is the full example:

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>use of table</title>
  
  <style>
  table{
    font-size: 25px;
    color: red;
  }
  </style>
  
</head>
<body>
  <center> 
 <p>Hello World this is a font check</p>

 <table border="3">
  <tr><td>Roll No</td> <td>195612</td> </tr>
  <tr><td>Name</td> <td>Rajesh</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Age</td> <td>23 (Twenty Three )</td> </tr>
  <tr><td>Father's Name</td> <td> Nayar</td> </tr>
  <tr><td>City</td> <td>Siwas Pali</td> </tr>
    </table>
  </center>
</body>


</html>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This always works for me

```
body,table { font-size:12px; }//or whatever size you wish to use
```

And As they have mentioned before, do all your styling in a CSS fole and link it to your project, thats the standard.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the font-size in the cell class, not the table class.

```
.my-table td{
    font-size:11px;
}

<table class="my-table">
  <tr>
    <td>test
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

This might be because of the fact that font tag is not supported by HTML 5. Set the font using CSS instead.

```
p{
  font-size: 80px;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>use of table</title>
</head>
<body>
 <center> 
<p>Hello World this is a font check</p>

 <table border="3">
  <tr><td>Roll No</td> <td>195612</td> </tr>
   <tr><td>Name</td> <td>Rajesh</td></tr>
   <tr><td>Age</td> <td>23 (Twenty Three )</td> </tr>
   <tr><td>Father's Name</td> <td> Nayar</td> </tr>
   <tr><td>City</td> <td>Siwas Pali</td> </tr>
   </table>
</center>
</body>


</html>
```

Take a look at this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/bala4kp/zxad0bc4/